# Is there any syntax to add additional info to an eslint-disable-line comment?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Given a comment like this:

```js
  i++; // eslint-disable-line no-plusplus
```

Is there any syntax we can add a description or explanation for why we're disabling the rule, on the same line, without triggering ESLint to complain that there's no rule called "-- our description"?

```js
  i++; // eslint-disable-line no-plusplus - our description
```

In this simple example it's trivial enough to use `// eslint-disable-next-line` - but in a situation where you have multiple lines that might change order like object keys, or import statements (if using automatic alphabetization) then that breaks down.

Is there any supported method for achieving this?

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/rfcs/pull/33, and it's called out in https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add two dashes `--`. According to the docs on [using configuration comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-comments):

> Configuration comments can include descriptions to explain why the comment is necessary. The description must occur after the configuration and is separated from the configuration by two or more consecutive `-` characters. For example:
>
> ```js
> /* eslint eqeqeq: "off", curly: "error" -- Here's a description  */
> ```

**Further Reading**: Added on Sep 2019 via [New: Description in directive comments](https://github.com/eslint/rfcs/pull/33)

Comment: @KyleMit thanks for the appreciation and the helpful edit!